ASP.NET Core Web API : authentication users files
I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project where users upload their own files, and these files are stored in folders corresponding to their IDs (GUIDs) on the same Linux server.
To serve these files externally, I use a domain called cdn.mydomain.com. However, the paths for the files returned from the CDN are accessible to all users and can even be seen by anyone, which creates the issue of one user being able to view another user's files.
I need to achieve two things:

Files should only be visible to logged-in users, meaning there should be authentication
A user should not be able to see files uploaded by other users


You could consider policy-based authorization with a custom handler to verify that users can only access their own files. Serve files through API endpoints rather than directly from the CDN, allowing the API to perform necessary authentication and authorization checks before returning the file.

@MdFaridUddinKiron Will returning large files via the API affect performance or memory?

Well, returning large files via the API can indeed impact performance and memory usage, especially if not handled efficiently. Instead of loading the entire file into memory, you can stream the file content. This approach helps in reducing memory usage and allows for better performance. In addition, you can enable response compression to reduce the amount of data transferred over the network. This can be particularly beneficial for large files.

you'll be placing the files in a directory where only your code can reach them.  (so no ability to link directly to files)  Then your endpoint will authorize and serve them by returning File.  (DB table can store filename/path, uid, user_id)  Endpoint can just be serve_file?uid=image_uid.  You can also set SRC's with same.
